# Cron job scheduled not running automatically in Node.js BOT

Tags: node.js, cron

I am working on a Bot, using BotFramework-node.js hosted on Azure.
I am using four cronjobs in my bot to run different functions at different points of a day. The only issue is that the jobs are not running automatically. They will run normally if i compile/run the code, but wont if i don't compile/run it within 12 hours  i.e, if i run the code manually today morning, the jobs will execute fine for today but tomorrow it won't unless i run it again.

Tried changing the modules. I have tried using node-schedule, node-cron. Now using cron

`var Name = new CronJob({ 
    cronTime:'0 15 11 * * 0-6', 
    onTick: function(){
        //function call / another js file call
    }
});
Name.start();`

Comment: Make sure that your Cron not running on your server with their timezone

Comment: Your time(local time) and cron time(server time) differ ?

Comment: i didn't get it @ŞivāSankĂr. I have't set any specific timezones. My Server's TimeZone is GMT.

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr yes

Comment: Cron will run on your server time only, you need to check on that time

Comment: I am giving the respected GMT time associated with IST @ŞivāSankĂr

Comment: Still its not working ?

Comment: It will execute if i run/compile the code again. Thats the issue. @ŞivāSankĂr